# Control what addthis shares

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

i´m working on a wordpress template.

I have this markup for the sharer:

```
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"">
            <a class="addthis_button_facebook" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_twitter" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
        </div>
```

The problem is that when I click to share on facebook it displays this:

[image]

As you can see, the title, url and image it´s ok, but it also shows the content in a weird way... is it possible to delete it or modify to share it in clean way?

Answer (score 1):

#### Meta Tags

It will be the same when you tried to share the URL and put it in `What's on your mind...` text box. You need to change the `<meta />` tags in your HTML Output.

So, to make the change, just add these tags:

```
<meta name="description" content="Whatever you want in the share body." />
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript" />
<meta name="author" content="Your Name" />
```

Comment: I didn´t modify any meta tag, just put the addthis button

Comment: I know, but did you try just putting the URL? It would show the same thing. It is not the problem with `AddThis`, but with the HTML Output.

Comment: it works perfect with that meta tags, thank you :)

Comment: is it possible to put on name="description" to get automatically the_content of the post?

Comment: Yea, you have to do that way.